# Updating Microsoft B2C identities with Graph SDK 5

Tags: c#

I'm upgrading client code that uses the Microsoft Graph nuget package from v4.54 to v5.4. I have code that works in v4 that updates the identities for a user exactly like [How to update identities collection for existing B2C User using Microsoft Graph and SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051028/how-to-update-identities-collection-for-existing-b2c-user-using-microsoft-graph).

All the updated functions in my code works, e.g. creating users, adding users to groups, etc., except for updating or adding identities to the user.
After [updating the Post to a Patch as required](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md), the code fails with an unexpected error:

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.MainError 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: signInType cannnot be null or empty  [sic]
```

I've run the request through Fiddler and the signInType is definitely not null.

Code before

```cs
user.Identities.Add(new ObjectIdentity
{
    SignInType = "emailAddress",
    Issuer = issuer,
    IssuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId
});
await client.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

Code after

```cs
user.Identities.Add(new ObjectIdentity
{
    SignInType = "emailAddress",
    Issuer = issuer,
    IssuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId
});
await client.Users[user.Id].PatchAsync(user);
```

I've also tried creating a new user object for the patch (same error):

```cs
var identities = user.Identities;
identities.Add(new ObjectIdentity
{
    SignInType = "emailAddress",
    Issuer = issuer,
    IssuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId
});
var requestBody = new User 
{
    Identities = identities
};
await client.Users[user.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody );
```

Has anyone successfully updated the Identities collection on a User with Graph v5.x?

Answer (score 1):

Since I saw your questions and I had planed to update to Graph v5.x too, I started working on it and hit the same problem. But fortunately I've found a way to solve it (change the email address in this sample):

```
            var user = await graphClient.Users[userid].GetAsync(requestConfig =>
            {
                requestConfig.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Identities", "DisplayName", "Id", "AccountEnabled" };
            });


            var newUsr = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.User();
            newUsr.Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>();
            newUsr.Identities.Add(
                new ObjectIdentity()
                {
                    SignInType = "emailAddress",
                    IssuerAssignedId = newEMail,
                    Issuer = user.Identities.First(i => i.SignInType == "emailAddress").Issuer
                }
            );

            await graphClient.Users[userid].PatchAsync(newUsr);
```

The trick seems to be, to only include the changed identity (and not both in my case) and also create a new ObjectIdentity instance (it doesn't work with the old instance from the get request) and fill the required attributes.